# Cauchy-Schwarz-like inequality for a self-adjoint nonnegativity-preserving operator on $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probability space and $A$ be a self-adjoint bounded linear operator on $L^2(\mu)$. Assume $Af\ge0$ for all $f\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)$ with $f\ge0$. Are we able to show the Cauchy-Schwarz-like inequality $$\langle Af,f\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}\le\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}^2\sup_{\substack{g\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)\\\left\|g\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\le1\\g\ge0}}\left\|Ag\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\tag1$$ for all $f\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)$ with $f\ge0$? Since the standard prove doesn't work, we need a different argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we assume that 
$f\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)$ with $f\ge0$ and $\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}=1$.
Then we have by the standard Cauchy-Schwartz that 
$$
\langle Af,f\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}\le
\| Af\|_{L^2(\mu)}\| f\|_{L^2(\mu)}=\| Af\|_{L^2(\mu)}
\le 
\sup_{\substack{g\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)\\\left\|g\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\le1\\g\ge0}}\left\|Ag\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\tag1.
$$
Now for arbitrary $f\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)$ with $f\ge0$ and $\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}>0$, we apply the result to the scaled function
$\tilde{f}=f/\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}$ and deduce that
$$
\langle A\frac{f}{\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}},\frac{f}{\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}}\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}
=\langle A\tilde{f},\tilde{f}\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}
\le 
\sup_{\substack{g\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)\\\left\|g\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\le1\\g\ge0}}\left\|Ag\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\tag1.
,
$$
which together with the linearity of $A$  gives us the desired inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry. This is trivial. I've actually tried to solve a slightly different problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3467325/47771. Maybe you can take a look.