# Show $\sup_{0≤f∈L^2}\frac{\|Af\|_{L^2}}{\|f\|_{L^2}}=\sup_{0≤f∈L^2}\frac{⟨Af,f⟩_{L^2}}{\|f\|_{L^2}^2}$ for self-adjoint nonnegativity-preserving $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a measure space and $A$ be a self-adjoint bounded linear operator on $L^2(\mu)$. Assume $Af\ge0$ for all $f\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)$ with $f\ge0$. Let $$c_1:=\sup_{\substack{f\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)\setminus\{0\}\\f\ge0}}\frac{\left\|Af\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}}{\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}}.$$

> I would like to show that $$c_1=\sup_{\substack{f\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)\setminus\{0\}\\f\ge0}}\frac{\langle Af,f\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}}{\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}^2}=:c_2.\tag1$$

Note that this is a classical result which is true when the suprema in the definitions of $c_1$ and $c_2$ are taken over $\mathcal L^2(\mu)\setminus\{0\}$ and we take the absolute value of the inner product in the definition of $c_2$.

Mimicing the usual proof, we easily obtain $$c_2\le c_1=\sup_{\substack{f,\:g\:\in\:\mathcal L^2(\mu)\\\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\:=\:\left\|g\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\:=\:1\\f,\:g\:\ge\:0}}\langle Af,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}=:c_3\tag2.$$ Now we the classical claim (without the nonnegativity condition in the domain over which the supremum is taken in the definition of $c_3$) is concluded by showing $$c_3\le c_2\tag3$$ using the [parallelogram law](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Parallelogram_Law_(Hilbert_Space)). Obviously, the problem with this is that the difference of nonnegative functions doesn't need to be nonnegative. Can we fix this or conclude by a different argument?

Comment: I saw your question yesterday, and it motivated me to think of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466225/on-the-definition-of-positive-operators), I have no answer, good question anyway.

Comment: @user284331 If $\kappa$ is any [transition kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel#Definition), then $\kappa f\ge0$ whenever $f\ge0$. Simply cause $(\kappa f)(x)=(\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;)f$ is the integral of a nonnegative function with respect to a nonnegative measure. In your situation, $K$ could be the density of a transition kernel with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @user284331 Regarding the ordering: It's the same as the one given on a general Hilbert lattice.

Comment: I suspect that there is something wrong with the question as stated. Unless I misunderstand something, if you know $(2)$ then the thing you'd want to prove is that $c_1 \leq c_3$. To do this, it'd be enough to show that for $f \geq 0$ with $\|f\| = 1$ we have that $\|Af\| \leq c_3$. If $Af = 0$ this is trivial. Otherwise, we can take $g = \|Af\|^{-1} Af$ to see that $\|Af\| \leq \langle Af, g \rangle \leq c_3$. Maybe the $\sup$ in $c_3$ is meant to be taken over non-negative functions or something?

Comment: @RhysSteele Maybe you were confused since I wrote $c_1\ge c_2$ (instead of $c_2\le c_1$); otherwise I don't know what you mean. If $(2)$ holds, then $c_2\le c_1=c_3$. So, if we can show that $c_3\le c_2$, we need to have $c_1=c_2$.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, of course I want to take the supremum only over nonnegative $f,g$. Sorry!

Comment: @RhysSteele Did I miss something or was the mistake on your side?

Comment: The question as written now seems fine. The problem was which of $c_1$ and $c_2$ you were saying you knew that $c_3$ was equal to I think. Before, your edit to replace \ge with \le you had written $c_1 \ge c_2 = c_3$ and so you would want to see that $c_3 \ge c_1$ to close which I was pointing out was straightforward. After the edit, you have written $c_2 \le c_1 = c_3$ and so the thing you want to prove to close the argument is indeed now $c_3 \le c_2$.

Comment: @RhysSteele Ah, sorry. I only looked at the inequality and didn't noticed that the equality was wrong before. Do you've got any idea for $(3)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the complex Hilbert space $L^{2}(\mu)$ is in issue, so the definition of $c_{2}$ and $c_{3}$ are respectively 
\begin{align*}
c_{2}=\sup_{f\geq 0,~\|f\|=1}\left<Af,f\right>_{r},
\end{align*}
and that
\begin{align*}
c_{3}=\sup_{f,g\geq 0,~\|f\|=\|g\|=1}\left|\left<Af,g\right>\right|,
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
\left<f,g\right>=\int f\overline{g},
\end{align*}
and that
\begin{align*}
\left<f,g\right>_{r}=\int fg.
\end{align*}

Let $f,g\geq 0$, $\|f\|=\|g\|=1$ be given. First of all, since $A(f)\geq 0$, it is trivial that $\left<Af,f\right>_{r}=\left<Af,f\right>$ and $\left|\left<Af,g\right>\right|=\left<Af,g\right>\geq 0$, so there is no need to distinguish $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>_{r}$ and $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$ in the definition of $c_{2}$ and $c_{3}$. The absolute value in $c_{3}$ can also be removed.

We know the formula that
\begin{align*}
4\text{Re}\left<Af,g\right>=\left<A(f+g),f+g\right>-\left<A(f-g),f-g\right>.
\end{align*}
But in this case, the term $\text{Re}\left<Af,g\right>$ simply becomes $\left<Af,g\right>$.

Now we let $h=f-g$, the crucial point is to realize that 
\begin{align*}
|A(h)|\leq A(|h|).
\end{align*}
Indeed, since $h$ is real-valued, we have $|h|+h\geq 0$. Since $h=h^{+}-h^{-}$, linearity of $A$ gives $Ah=Ah^{+}-Ah^{-}$. Keep in mind that both $Ah^{+},Ah^{-}\geq 0$, so $Ah$ is real-valued.

As $A$ is order-preserving, we have $A(|h|+h)\geq 0$, linearity of $A$ and the fact that $Ah$ being real-valued give $A(|h|)\geq-A(h)$. The same account applies to $|h|-h\geq 0$ to get $A(|h|)\geq A(h)$.

As a result, 
\begin{align*}
\left|\left<A(f-g),f-g\right>\right|\leq\left<|A(f-g)|,|f-g|\right>\leq\left<A(|f-g|),|f-g|\right>.
\end{align*}
We obtain that 
\begin{align*}
& 4\left<Af,g\right>\\
&\leq\|f+g\|^{2}\left|\left<A\left(\dfrac{f+g}{\|f+g\|}\right),\dfrac{f+g}{\|f+g\|}\right>\right|+\|f-g\|^{2}\left|\left<A\left(\dfrac{|f-g|}{\|f-g\|}\right),\dfrac{|f-g|}{\|f-g\|}\right>\right|\\
&=\|f+g\|^{2}\left<A\left(\dfrac{f+g}{\|f+g\|}\right),\dfrac{f+g}{\|f+g\|}\right>+\|f-g\|^{2}\left<A\left(\dfrac{|f-g|}{\|f-g\|}\right),\dfrac{|f-g|}{\|f-g\|}\right>\\
&\leq c_{2}(\|f+g\|^{2}+\|f-g\|^{2})\\
&= 2c_{2}(\|f\|^{2}+\|g\|^{2})\\
&= 4c_{2},
\end{align*}
so $\left<Af,g\right>\leq c_{2}$, and hence $c_{3}\leq c_{2}$ is claimed.

Comment: Thank you! What you wrote is indeed the crucial point. The rest is the same as for the standard result.

Comment: Note that the first equality after "We obtain that" should be "$\le$".